# How to do QRD RLS in MATLAB 17

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB 17. I want to denoise an EEG signal using QRD RLS. I would like to use [dsp.RLSFilter System object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.rlsfilter-class.html). I tried other decomposition methods. But those methods worked well. When I used QRD RLS it gave error. The code was like

```
rls2 = dsp.RLSFilter('Length', 11, 'Method', 'QR decomposition');
```

In the output segment it showed.

```
Error in matlab.system.SystemProp/setProperties

Error in dsp.RLSFilter (line 280)
            setProperties(obj, nargin, varargin{:},'Length');
```

Comment: As your error states 'QR decomposition' is not a valid Method(You have not posted this part of the error) . Try: rls2 = dsp.RLSFilter('Length', 11, 'Method', 'QR-decomposition RLS');

Answer (score 0):

```
rls2 = dsp.RLSFilter('Length', 11, 'Method', 'QR-decomposition RLS');
```